# Retracts in the bicategory of spans

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, 2-categories

I would like to show that the category of sets and spans between them, seen as a $(2,1)$-category, is Cauchy complete, i.e. has splitting of (homotopicaly coherent) idempotent.

Ideally I would also like to prove that the retract of a set $X$ in this bi-category are all subsets of $X$, and that all this also works if we replace set by a category with finite limits.

I think I have a poof of this (If I'm not mistaken), but it is very long and technical and I wanted to know if there is literature about this, or if there is a simpler or more conceptual way to obtain these results.

Comment: I think I worked something out [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308567/what-is-the-idempotent-completion-of-the-2-1-category-of-spans-of-finite-sets) but ... erm ... I definitely skipped some bits that seemed technical :)